# What is a word for when someone likes bodily harm done to oneself.

Tags: epithet-requests

What word would work for someone who likes to be hurt by other people? Physically, like it may even be a turn on.

Answer (score 1):

You call that someone a **masochist**.

> 1. a person who has masochism, the **condition in which sexual or other gratification depends on one's suffering physical pain**
>      or humiliation.
> 2. a person who is **gratified by pain, degradation**, etc., that is self-imposed or imposed by others.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/masochist

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to ***[masochism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/masochism):***

> - gratification gained from pain, deprivation, degradation, etc., inflicted or imposed on oneself, either as a result of one's own actions or the actions of others, especially the tendency to seek this form of gratification.

Word Origin:

> - *"sexual pleasure in being hurt or abused," 1892, from German Masochismus, coined 1883 by German neurologist Richard von Krafft-Ebing (1840-1902), **from name of Leopold von Sacher- Masoch (1836-1895)**, Austrian utopian socialist novelist who enshrined his submissive sexuality in "Venus in Furs" (1869, German title "Venus im Pelz").*

(dictionary.reference.com)